# openvz performance issues

Tags: openvz

I have two VEs running on the same physical server.  One VE sends requests and the other reads/processes them.   I'm trying to benchmark the setup, but I keep blowing through the UBC limits. Things grind to a halt when this happens. Is there a way I can completely disable UBC so it doesn't keep hitting limits?  Or is the only way to do something like this to set the UBC params to extraordinarily high values?

Comment: Can you please post the contents of /prov/user_beancounters for the container that you are benchmarking in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVZ can be a bit difficult to set limits for. Documentation is not very clear and the configuration is quite arcane if you are a first timer. Instead of using the example configurations, I would encourage you to use [`vzsplit`](http://man.cx/vzsplit) to help set up your limits. That solved a lot of my problems when hitting limits. The generic configuration does not fit all sizes.

Comment: I am a first timer, and had the same issues as the poster, then as you said I-ve found about vzsplit, and really made my day, although I had a minor problem with CPUUNITS, which finally turn out to be a bug: http://bugzilla.openvz.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1627

Answer (score 0):

If you're hitting the limits, either you've set the limits too low or you're doing something extraordinarily wrong.  I'd raise the limits to appropriate levels for your hardware, and then if that doesn't help, investigate what the code is doing wrong.